# Docker, Redis Cluster, Go, failed to establish a connection

Tags: docker, go, redis

OS Windows 11. Created a Redis cluster in Docker.
docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis-1:
    container_name: "redis-1"
    image: redis:7.2-rc-alpine3.18
    ports:
      - 7000:7000
      - 17000:17000
    volumes:
      - "./redis/redis.conf:/etc/redis.conf"
    command: redis-server /etc/redis.conf --port 7000
    network_mode: "host"
  
  redis-2:
    container_name: "redis-2"
    image: redis:7.2-rc-alpine3.18
    ports:
      - 7001:7001
      - 17001:17001
    volumes:
      - "./redis/redis.conf:/etc/redis.conf"
    command: redis-server /etc/redis.conf --port 7001
    network_mode: "host"
  
  redis-3:
    container_name: "redis-3"
    image: redis:7.2-rc-alpine3.18
    ports:
      - 7002:7002
      - 17002:17002
    volumes:
      - "./redis/redis.conf:/etc/redis.conf"
    command: redis-server /etc/redis.conf --port 7002
    network_mode: "host"
 
  redis-4:
    container_name: "redis-4"
    image: redis:7.2-rc-alpine3.18
    ports:
      - 7003:7003
      - 17003:17003
    volumes:
      - "./redis/redis.conf:/etc/redis.conf"
    command: redis-server /etc/redis.conf --port 7003
    network_mode: "host"
  
  redis-5:
    container_name: "redis-5"
    image: redis:7.2-rc-alpine3.18
    ports:
      - 7004:7004
      - 17004:17004
    volumes:
      - "./redis/redis.conf:/etc/redis.conf"
    command: redis-server /etc/redis.conf --port 7004
    network_mode: "host"
  
  redis-6:
    container_name: "redis-6"
    image: redis:7.2-rc-alpine3.18
    ports:
      - 7005:7005
      - 17005:17005
    volumes:
      - "./redis/redis.conf:/etc/redis.conf"
    command: redis-server /etc/redis.conf --port 7005
    network_mode: "host"
```

There is a simple Go code:

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
 
    "github.com/redis/go-redis/v9"
)
 
var ctx = context.Background()
 
func main() {
    c := redis.NewClusterClient(&redis.ClusterOptions{
        Addrs: []string{"127.0.0.1:7001"},
    })
 
    if err := c.Ping(ctx).Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unable to connect to redis " + err.Error())
    }
}
```

After launch, an error occurs: "dial tcp 127.0.0.1:7001: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YroL7.png

If run one separate Redis container in Docker, built from one image, then it turns out to connect to "127.0.0.1:6379"

Comment: Could it have something to do with the network_mode you are using in your docker-compose.yaml file ? host is not supported on Windows -> https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/#prerequisites

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip! Replaced the lines "network_mode: host" in all services with "networks: 
   -cluster", uniting them into one network. And at the end of the file added:
"networks:
   cluster:
     driver:bridge".

Now the connection problem is gone.